# How can user explorer data from Google Analytics be exported?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am looking for the solution that will help me create the following table of data:

- user IDs (or users) will be listed as rows
- visited pages by users (including conversions)

Can you share how it could be done via API or with use of R?

Thank you for your help.

All the best,

Lukas

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be done via the API (a design decision by Google). You could create custom dimensions for UserId and ClientId and use that (does not work retroactively; also, ask your lawyer first about privacy legislation).

If you have an Google 360 account you could do an export to BigQuery, which would include UserId and ClientId.

Comment: Your answer was not loaded until I published mine and after that I saw you wrote a similar answer but earlier. So I will remove mine and put it as a comment here!
I think that this cannot be done in any way by just using the built-in userId feature, it is documented here https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6205850#reporting . This can only be done by implementing a custom dimension to store the userId that you are sending to GA, that way you have the required flexibility to query those metrics you want